# SharePoint site take too much time after iis reset to open

Tags: 2013

When I restart my IIS; `IISReset` my sharepoint foundation site takes so much time to come back, it was okay before. my Server is super fast so it cannot be memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could be related to this issue:

**Problem**

> Why does SharePoint need IIS_WPG – that’s a different topic. This
>   group used to be a local security group on the default installation of
>   IIS 6 (Windows Server 2003) and SharePoint 2007 (MOSS) would add the
>   SharePoint application pool accounts to this group. I don’t know what
>   problems you will run into if you delete the IIS_WPG group in MOSS
>   2007/WSS 3.0, but you should definitely not delete it.
>
> The group went away with IIS7/Windows Server 2008, but SharePoint
>   still tries to find it, which is what creates the slowness. This
>   behavior is same for both MOSS 2007/WSS 3.0 and SharePoint 2010

**solution**

> All you need to do is create a local security group named “IIS_WPG” on
>   each SharePoint server in the farm, and after that, central
>   administration web site should load without any delays.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tehnoonr/archive/2012/05/17/sharepoint-central-administration-web-site-takes-a-long-time-to-load-after-an-iis-reset.aspx

i also belive that the more you user sharepoint and by that i mean load/add more stuff to homepage ect would take longer to load than an ootb page. When you do a reset all blob chache and any other chaching is gone and needs to reload all services, iis settings and accounts assosiated to the site your trying to load, so the initial first load is going to be slow but after that it would go back to normal!

Comment: fusion logging was on thats why it was slow